# Does OData query support nested filters with AND/OR operators?

Tags: odata

Does OData query support nested filters with AND/OR operators?

By nested query, I mean query similar to this:

((FieldA < 50 OR FieldA > 100) AND FieldB == "MyString")

I am building an OData query editor control, so I need to know if these are available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes it does. E.g.:

```
GET http://services.odata.org/v4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=(FirstName ne 'Mary' and LastName ne 'White') and UserName ne 'marywhite'
```

You can try it yourself in a browser.

Comment: what is the d: and d/ here?

Comment: @RainCast Like the lambda in C#, they are input parameters. You can replace it with any name.

Comment: @RainCast I think I misread your question. But the answer is valid. Let me edit my answer to a better fit.

Comment: @RainCast Done. In one word OData supports nested filters.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a conclusive example since all for all the AND operators the result would be the same even without parentheses. Show an example with OR.

Comment: Trying to use OR operator would result in the following error: "The 'OR' operator is not supported on distinct fields on an OData filter".