# Dynamics NAV - apply range filter using OData

Tags: dynamics-nav

How can a range filter such as 'a..d|e|f|g..k' be applied against a field using OData?

Example:
http://navserver/instance/OData/Company('Company')/entity$format=json&$filter=property eq 'a..d|e|f|g..k'

This URL format will fail. Is there a way to apply such range without custom NAV code ?

Answer (score 1):

I have always taken the approach of translating the query from NAV Style Filtering to the Native oData types, which provides a filter like this:

```
$filter=(property gt 'a' and property lt 'd') or property eq 'e' or property eq 'f' or (property gt 'g' and property lt 'k')
```

There is a list of the way that you can map NAV filter values to oData on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169248(v=nav.90).aspx)

Note the [nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818345/does-odata-query-support-nested-filters-with-and-or-operators) to get it to deliver the results you would look for out of NAV.

Not your actual question, but if you want to use the NAV style filtering you can look into the SOAP services, as they do support more NAV style filters, [example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-c-using-web-reference/).